# JSX type checking for child elements

Tags: typescript, jsx, tsx

I have written a custom JSX implementation for a non-React project.

```
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      row: {};
      button: {
        id?: string;
        style?: string;
        disabled?: boolean;
        url?: string;
      };
      select: {
        id?: string;
        disabled?: boolean;
        placeholder?: string;
      };
      opt: { val: string; desc: string; default?: boolean };
    }
  }
}

export function createElement(type: any, props: any, ...children: any[]) {}
export const Fragment = {};
```

I want to restrict how the elements can be composed. For instance, a fragment should only contain rows, which should only contain select and button. A select should not contain a row etc.

```
const test = (
  <>
    <row>
      <button>Click me</button>
    </row>
    <row>
      <select id="test-menu">
        <opt val="test1" desc="test">Test</opt>
        <opt val="test2" desc="test">Test</opt>
      </select>
    </row>
    // Should not be valid
    <select>
      <row></row>
    </select>
  </>
);
```

I don't really know how to achieve this or whether it's even possible as using JSX outside of React seems to be quite uncommon.